# Combine numbers from two columns to create one array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code to create sample dataframe:

```
Sample = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': [[.332, .326], [.058, .138]]},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': [[.234, .246], [.234, .395]]},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample)
```

Sample Dataframe visualized:

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]
```

I'm looking for a formula to combine Jan and Feb columns into one array, outputting in a New column this array.

Expected output:

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar                             New
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138]   |    [150, 200]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395]  |    [200, 210]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]   |    [50, 90]
```

Comment: Be mindful of the speed of apply.  See my post for a comparison of the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## *List comprehension*

This is the way to go if you're looking for *speed*.

```
df['New'] = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(df.Jan, df.Feb)]
df

   Feb  Jan                               Mar    account         New
0  200  150  [[0.332, 0.326], [0.058, 0.138]]  Jones LLC  [150, 200]
1  210  200  [[0.234, 0.246], [0.234, 0.395]]   Alpha Co  [200, 210]
2   90   50   [[0.084, 0.23], [0.745, 0.923]]   Blue Inc    [50, 90]
```

If you want to drop your original columns, you can use

```
df.drop(['Jan', 'Feb'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

## `df.apply` with `axis=1`

This is here for the sake of completion—I do not condone the use of `apply` anymore.

```
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['Jan'], x['Feb']], axis=1)    
df

   Feb  Jan                               Mar    account         New
0  200  150  [[0.332, 0.326], [0.058, 0.138]]  Jones LLC  [150, 200]
1  210  200  [[0.234, 0.246], [0.234, 0.395]]   Alpha Co  [200, 210]
2   90   50   [[0.084, 0.23], [0.745, 0.923]]   Blue Inc    [50, 90]
```

---

**Performance**
Repeating piR's tests for small data (3000 rows) including the list comprehension method, we have—

```
%timeit df.assign(New=df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist())
%timeit df.assign(New=df.apply(lambda x: [x['Jan'], x['Feb']], axis=1))
%timeit df.assign(New=[[x, y] for x, y in zip(df.Jan, df.Feb)])

2.76 ms ± 596 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
152 ms ± 9.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.59 ms ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

And for larger data (30,000 rows)—

```
5.95 ms ± 527 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.53 s ± 165 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
8.79 ms ± 793 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Both the list comprehension and the `.tolist()` are competitive methods. Which one you decide to use is a matter of taste. Do *not* use `apply`!

Comment: ! Thank you. This worked. I can't accept an answer for another few minutes but I will :)

Answer (score 8):

Use `values.tolist`

```
df.assign(New=df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist())
# inplace... use this
# df['New'] = df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist()

   Feb  Jan                               Mar    account         New
0  200  150  [[0.332, 0.326], [0.058, 0.138]]  Jones LLC  [200, 150]
1  210  200  [[0.234, 0.246], [0.234, 0.395]]   Alpha Co  [210, 200]
2   90   50   [[0.084, 0.23], [0.745, 0.923]]   Blue Inc    [90, 50]
```

**Timing with larger data**
Avoiding `apply` is more than 60 times faster with a 3,000 row dataframe.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.assign(New=df[['Feb', 'Jan']].values.tolist())
%timeit df.assign(New=df.apply(lambda x: [x['Jan'], x['Feb']], axis=1))

1000 loops, best of 3: 947 µs per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 61.7 ms per loop
```

And 160 times faster for 30,000 row dataframe

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.58 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 586 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also try  `df['New'] = list(zip(df.Feb, df.Jan))`

or using `tolist` `df['New'] = df.ix[:,0:2].values.tolist()`

Comment: Ya know, this post taught me that pandas can be nice, and cutthroat at the same time. Edited my answer.